# How to use scss directly in React components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to use scss directly in my components. Now I import css like this:

```
import './test.css';

return (
    <Container>
      <Col sm="12">
        <div className="test_wrapper">
```

I want to use like this:
   import './test.scss';

```
return (
    <Container>
      <Col sm="12">
        <div className="test_wrapper">
```

Comment: `import './test.scss'`

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

Comment: @Hoyen I think it was a joke....

Comment: @Boy With Silver Wings and what next? I already have that plugin

Comment: @Hoyen is not joking.

Comment: okay I did that and my styles disapired

Comment: Attempt to use CommonJS' `require()` here. So `require("./test.scss")`.

Comment: I use react here

Comment: @rick if you are using weback, you need to install the `sass-loader` ind configure the module loaders

Comment: I installed everything but I do not know how to configure it to use sass directly in my components

Comment: can anybody instead of writing 100 comments just provide example?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already suggest, you need to install a webpack loader for scss.

`npm i -D sass-loader`

And add the rule to your webpack configuration.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [ 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ],
},
```

If you are using jest, you should also look into `jest-css-modules`, or you will run into problems.

Comment: I do not use jest

Comment: {
           test: /\.scss$/,
              use: [{
                  loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
              }, {
                  loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
              }, {
                  loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
              }]
          },
I have such a config in webpack.config.js bug it doesnt work

Comment: Maybe you are missing the `style-loader`? That is the one that actually "applies" the styles. `css-loader` merely takes it in and puts in the JS file. `{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }` Ref https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader